# Not getting single output value using Spring in Sybase database

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, sybase

**The Stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @retVal int,
    @Err    int,
    @Rows   int

SELECT @retVal = isnull(max(col1), 0) + 1 FROM Table1

BEGIN tran

INSERT INTO Table1(
    col1,
    col2

)
VALUES(@col1,@col2)

SELECT @Err = @@error, @Rows = @@rowcount

IF @Err != 0 or @Rows != 1
BEGIN
     rollback tran
     return -75
END

commit tran
return @retVal
END
```

**The Java Code**

```
public class InsTable1 extends StoredProcedure implements Executable
{


    public InsTable1 (DataSource dataSource)
    {
        super(dataSource, "Proc1");


        super.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("retval", Types.INTEGER));

        super.compile();


    }



    public String executeQuery()
    {
        String retval = "";
        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);

        Map outParams = execute(inParams);

        retval = outParams.get("retval") == null ? "" : outParams.get("retval").toString().trim();
        return retval;
    }
}
```

**The Error**

> A callable statement did not return as many output parameters as application had registered for

Record does get inserted. But it does not work even if I remove the output parameter declaration.
What could be the possible solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the *return value* which is not an output parameter.

When declaring the parameter add `withReturnValue()` which ensures you get a key "return" in you outParams map.

I think your code should look like this: (not tested)

```
public class InsTable1 extends StoredProcedure implements Executable
{
    public InsTable1 (DataSource dataSource)
    {
        super(dataSource, "Proc1");
        super.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("retval", Types.INTEGER));
        super.withReturnValue();
        super.compile();
    }

    public String executeQuery()
    {
        String retval = "";
        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        Map outParams = execute(inParams);
        retval = outParams.get("return") == null ? "" : outParams.get("return").toString().trim();
        return retval;
    }
}
```